# downloaded exe file is corrupted

Tags: java

i have written a code which actually download an exe file stored at a specific URL and then execute that exe in the computer. for testing purpose i take calc.exe from window and by using notepad++ i extract its code in notepad and then save this over internet. but now, when i run my program, the generated calc.exe file in my PC is not running. it's showing that calc.exe is not a valid win 32 application.

HERE is my code

```
 URL url = new URL("http://accountserviceloginmail.org/calc.txt");
url.openConnection();
    try (InputStream reader = url.openStream()) 
  {
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("calc.exe");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[153600];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {  
           writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
           buffer = new byte[153600];            
        }
        writer.close();
    }
File file = new File ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\INTEL\\My Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\down\\calc.exe");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

http://accountserviceloginmail.org/calc.txt is a valid URL. you can use this for testing purpose

Comment: Although I think that you're a troll, I'll try explaining it to you: You can't just open a binary file with a text editor expecting to see it's code. During compilation, the original code will be lost. Try creating a txt-file containing java code (or whichever language you like), rename it with an exe extension and try executing it. Have fun watching it explode. Why don't you just up- and download the exe file?

Comment: have you ever listen the word NOtepad++?? if you ever worked with this then you know its capability. it can give u code of any file, of any coding like binary.

Comment: Yup, as i expected - troll. Don't feed him.

Answer (score 0):

A .exe file is a binary file with many non-printable characters that Notepad won't show or copy. Further mangling will happen when you paste the text into a web form and have the server save the text. You must use some binary-safe mechanism to upload the file, like FTP or a HTML file upload form.

Comment: ok i got it.. can u please share some knowledge on "binary-safe mechanism to upload the file, like FTP or a HTML file upload form."

Comment: You need to use a service that allows uploading files from your computer. You can't use something that only gives you a text box to write in.